# Spring Boot App Unit Test not running

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

When I try to run this code, spring boot app runs but the junit test case never runs.
But if I remove "@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)", then Junit tests runs but my spring boot app does not run. 
In my earlier projects this was never a problem.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DataloaderSafetyRankingsTests {

    @Test
    public void testRandom() {
        assertEquals(5, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"When I try to run this code"_ -- HOW do you try to run the code?  You need to provide a lot more details, and don't assume we can guess everything we can't see.

Comment: Does it change anything if you import org.junit.Assert; and say Assert.assertEquals(5, 2);

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `@Test annotation` is not from `Junit`. This usually results in test case getting omitted.

Comment: My god thank you! I imported `org.junit.Test` instead of `org.junit.jupyter.api.Test` and now it works after 1 hour!